# How to consider brackets as multiplication when doing eval in python?

Tags: python, syntax, integer

How to consider `eval("2(4)")` as 8?

When I run this it gives the error of `SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?`

---

***Editor's note:** There is an actual error in addition to the warning. In full (on Python 3.8):*

```
>>> eval("2(4)")
<string>:1: SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You cannot, this is not part of python's syntax.

Comment: `eval` is for *evaluating python code*. That will always be a syntax error

Comment: eval simply (eval)uates what's input as code, so, you're limited to the python syntax. However, there are *libraries to parse math equations* that can interpret that (I've actually used one, just don't remember the name). **Edit:** but I'm not sure if any of them CAN parse parentheses as multiplication.

Comment: simpleeval is such a library

Comment: As a side note, the usage of `eval` is pretty much always bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, `eval` will run the string you give it, and `2(4)` is a [call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) expression.

> ```
> call ::=  primary "(" [argument_list [","] | comprehension] ")"
> ```

This would make `2` the primary, which needs a `__call__` attribute but does not have one as it is just an `int`.

Hence the `SyntaxWarning: 'int' object is not callable`.